# Why is my rigged model not moving as one?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I'm fairly new to blender. Does anyone know how I can just get the model to be consistent and not come apart when moving the bones? Why are the belt and shirt not staying together?

[image]

Comment: have you tried to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode?

Comment: please provide your blend file if you are not willing to or don't know which information you have to provide....